# I can't compile SimGrid - S4U

Tags: c++, linux, simgrid

How to compile a C ++ simulation in SimGrid? I am using Ubuntu, following the installation steps in the documentation but when I try to test some example of the documentation itself, there are several errors and warnings.

I went to the examples folder and tried to run some of the S4U interface, but without success.

I tried this: g++ example.cpp -o example

And:
[erros and warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GiBw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Build example:**

```
tar xvf simgrid-3.27.tar.gz
cd simgrid-3.27/ && mkdir build && cd build/
cmake ..
make
make tests      ## build tests and examples
sudo make install
```

The `make` options https://simgrid.org/doc/latest/Installing_SimGrid.html .. ( Ref. https://simgrid.org/doc/latest/index.html )   **and** `simgrid-3.27/docs/source/Installing_SimGrid.rst`,
line 342:- make tests: Build the tests and examples.

When the examples have been built, the executable´s are in "build/examples/..". E.g. `simgrid-3.27/build/examples/cpp/actor-create/s4u-actor-create`